# Javascript snake game not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What's wrong with my code here? My Snake is not working as in the book's code. The code is taken for the excellent book "JavaScript for Kids" by Nick Morgan. I downloaded the code from the book and it seems identical to mine, am I missing something?

See JSFiddle here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/raenset/ehjyt08k/
```

Code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

var score = 0;

var drawBorder = function () {

  ctx.fillStyle = "Gray";
  ctx.fillRect (0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect (0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect (0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect (width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};

var drawScore = function () {

ctx.font = "20px Courier";
ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);

};

var gameOver = function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);

};

var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle){
    ctx.fill();
  }
  else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var Block = function (col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};

Block.prototype.drawSquare = function (color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.col * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};

Block.prototype.drawCircle = function (color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};

Block.prototype.equal = function (otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
  new Block (7, 5),
  new Block (6, 5),
  new Block (5, 5)
  ];

  this.direction = "right";
  this.nextDirection = "right";
};

Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
  }
};

Snake.prototype.move = function () {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;

  this.direction = this.nextDirection;

  if (this.direction === "right"){
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  }
  else if (this.direction === "down"){
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  }
  else if (this.direction === "left"){
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  }
  else if (this.direction === "up"){
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row -1);
  }

  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }
  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)){
    score++;
    apple.move();
  }
  else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
};

Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks -1);

  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  var selfCollision = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++){
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true;
    }
  }
  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function (newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down"){
    return;
  }
  else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left"){
    return;
  }
  else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
  }
  else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right"){
    return;
  }
  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};

var Apple = function () {
  this.position = new Block (10, 10);
};

Apple.prototype.draw = function () {
  this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};

Apple.prototype.move = function () {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks -2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) +1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};

var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();

var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);

var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions [event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html><head><title>Snake!</title> </head><body> <canvas id ="canvas" width ="400" height ="400"> </canvas> </body></html>
```

Here is the working code from the book. The problem is: where is it different from mine?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Snake!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <script>
    // Set up canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Get the width and height from the canvas element
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    // Work out the width and height in blocks
    var blockSize = 10;
    var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
    var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

    // Set score to 0
    var score = 0;

    // Draw the border
    var drawBorder = function () {
      ctx.fillStyle = "Gray";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
      ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
      ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
    };

    // Draw the score in the top-left corner
    var drawScore = function () {
      ctx.font = "20px Courier";
      ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
      ctx.textAlign = "left";
      ctx.textBaseline = "top";
      ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
    };

    // Clear the interval and display Game Over text
    var gameOver = function () {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      ctx.font = "60px Courier";
      ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);
    };

    // Draw a circle (using the function from Chapter 14)
    var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      if (fillCircle) {
        ctx.fill();
      } else {
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    };

    // The Block constructor
    var Block = function (col, row) {
      this.col = col;
      this.row = row;
    };

    // Draw a square at the block's location
    Block.prototype.drawSquare = function (color) {
      var x = this.col * blockSize;
      var y = this.row * blockSize;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
    };

    // Draw a circle at the block's location
    Block.prototype.drawCircle = function (color) {
      var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
      var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
    };

    // Check if this block is in the same location as another block
    Block.prototype.equal = function (otherBlock) {
      return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
    };

    // The Snake constructor
    var Snake = function () {
      this.segments = [
        new Block(7, 5),
        new Block(6, 5),
        new Block(5, 5)
      ];

      this.direction = "right";
      this.nextDirection = "right";
    };

    // Draw a square for each segment of the snake's body
    Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
        this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
      }
    };

    // Create a new head and add it to the beginning of
    // the snake to move the snake in its current direction
    Snake.prototype.move = function () {
      var head = this.segments[0];
      var newHead;

      this.direction = this.nextDirection;

      if (this.direction === "right") {
        newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
      } else if (this.direction === "down") {
        newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
      } else if (this.direction === "left") {
        newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
      } else if (this.direction === "up") {
        newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
      }

      if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
        gameOver();
        return;
      }

      this.segments.unshift(newHead);

      if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
        score++;
        apple.move();
      } else {
        this.segments.pop();
      }
    };

    // Check if the snake's new head has collided with the wall or itself
    Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
      var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
      var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
      var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
      var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);

      var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

      var selfCollision = false;

      for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
        if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
          selfCollision = true;
        }
      }

      return wallCollision || selfCollision;
    };

    // Set the snake's next direction based on the keyboard
    Snake.prototype.setDirection = function (newDirection) {
      if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
        return;
      } else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
        return;
      } else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
        return;
      } else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
        return;
      }

      this.nextDirection = newDirection;
    };

    // The Apple constructor
    var Apple = function () {
      this.position = new Block(10, 10);
    };

    // Draw a circle at the apple's location
    Apple.prototype.draw = function () {
      this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
    };

    // Move the apple to a new random location
    Apple.prototype.move = function () {
      var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
      var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
      this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
    };

    // Create the snake and apple objects
    var snake = new Snake();
    var apple = new Apple();

    // Pass an animation function to setInterval
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      drawScore();
      snake.move();
      snake.draw();
      apple.draw();
      drawBorder();
    }, 100);

    // Convert keycodes to directions
    var directions = {
      37: "left",
      38: "up",
      39: "right",
      40: "down"
    };

    // The keydown handler for handling direction key presses
    $("body").keydown(function (event) {
      var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
      if (newDirection !== undefined) {
        snake.setDirection(newDirection);
      }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS here is my html too:
`code`
<!DOCTYPE html>



    <title>Snake!</title>


<body>

<canvas id ="canvas" width ="400" height ="400"> </canvas>
    </body>`code`

Comment: In your fiddle, if you remove the "<script>" part at the start of your JavaScript code, it'll run.

Comment: Sure, but I want it to run as a "snake game", not as it does now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  tag from the top line of the jsfiddle script area and your code will work.  Jsfiddle doesn't like script tags inside the script area.